# How to connect my Next.js app to MongoDB Compass?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-compass

I am doing a Next.js project called NetMapper. Basically, I am creating a web interface for the CLI tool `nmap`. I am creating a Sign In/Sign Up forms and I need to store users in MongoDB Compass. I tried all sorts of things that I saw from youtube but it doesn't work. I have created *Schema* and *Model* for users but I can't connect to MongoDB Compass.

I installed *mongoose* for that

I did:

```js
const connectDb = async () => mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/netmapper);
```

But what do I do next ? How to use the Model that I created and actually insert data from the form in that database ?

Comment: There are plenty of guides on integrating mongodb with next.js. Take a look at [the official MongoDB guide](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/nextjs-with-mongodb/) and [Next.js typescript implementation on Github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/lib/mongodb.ts)

Comment: @MTN Yes, but what do I do with it ? I need to connect to MongoDB Compass and insert data when the form is submitted. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

- First, create a .env.local file in the root and store db credentials in it

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/netmapper
```

If this is not working, replace localhost with 0.0.0.0

- Connect to mongo

  ```
      async function connectToMongo() {
      try {
           await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
           console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
         } catch (error) {
           console.error("Error connecting to MongoDB:", error);
           throw error;
          }
      };
  ```
- Create a schema

  ```
      const testSchema = new Schema({
         name: String,
         email: String
      });

      const Test = models.Test|| model("Test", testSchema );
  ```
- Accept the request and send the response by creating a api/xyz.js file

  ```
  async function handler(req, res) {
      if (req.method === "POST") {
          const data = req.body;

          try {
              await connectToMongo();
              await Test.create(data);

              res.status(201).json({ message: "Test Inserted!" });
          } catch (error) {
              res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
          }
      }
  };
  ```
- Lastly send your form data

  ```
   async function submitFormHandler(formData) {
      const response = await fetch("/api/xyz", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
    }
  ```